# Android send sms pending Intent

Tags: android, sms

I'm using the following code to send SMS in my android app:

```
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, new Intent(PENDING), 0);
    activity.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                    sendJsonData(false);
                    break;
                }

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE: {
                    sendJsonData(true);
                    break;
                }

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: {
                    sendJsonData(true);
                    break;
                }

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU: {
                    sendJsonData(true);
                    break;
                }

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF: {
                    sendJsonData(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void sendJsonData(boolean error) {
        }
     }, new IntentFilter(PENDING));

    PendingIntent deliveryIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    activity.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.i(TAG, "got here");
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "got here");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

My question is when I get `RESULT_OK`, how can I know the `_id` column of the cursor adapter? I need this ID later. I can check for the `_id` later but is there a way to get it from the `pendingIntent`?

I'm not getting any callback on the `deliveryIntent` after delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is when I get `RESULT_OK`, how can I know the `_id` column of the cursor adapter?

You can put a `ContentObserver` on the SMS Provider in order to receive a callback when the message gets written, and then query the Provider to get the message ID. I've an example of how to do that in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098069). You would just need to change `"thread_id"` to `"_id"`.

> I can check for the `_id` later but is there a way to get it from the `pendingIntent`?

The only extra that's documented to come with that `Intent` is an optional additional error code for general failures. If you were to inspect the extras on any actual running example, however, you're likely to find several that are undocumented, one of which is possibly a content URI for the message, possibly keyed with `"uri"`. That's probably not consistent everywhere, though, so I wouldn't rely on it.

> I'm not getting any callback on the `deliveryIntent` after delivery.

That's not unusual. The delivery `PendingIntent` will only fire if confirmation is received from the service center, but not every wireless provider offers that functionality.

Comment: How can I get the exact `_id` then from the `ContentProvider`? If the user sends multiple of same messages, i.e "Test", how can I know the `_id` of which one I'm currently trying to send?

Comment: You can put a `ContentObserver` on the SMS Provider to receive a callback when the message gets written. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36098069) is what I'm describing, though you'd change `"thread_id"` to `"_id"`.

Comment: Your comment was the answer. Please put it in the main answer!

Comment: Sure thing. I guess I missed the actual question, and just answered about the `PendingIntent`. My bad. I'll add it here in a minute or two, when I get a chance. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: A very late question, but i wanted to know what is meant by errorClass  in the sending pending intent.

Comment: @Nabajyoti Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.