# SMS Pending Intent get the _id of the SMS or MMS that was sent

Tags: android, sms, mms

Currently i'm able to send SMS and MMS messages with no problem. My issue is that when I have a `PendingIntent` for the sent confirmation, how can I get the `_id` of the message that was sent? Is there a way to refer to that one sms? I'm doing the below:

```
    Intent sentIntent = new Intent(id_value);
    PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String result = "";

            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }, new IntentFilter(id_value));
```

In the above example, `id_value` is a random value I generate to identify which SMS or MMS was sent. But I want to know, what is the `_id` of the message in the SMS and MMS db's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `uri` key in the `extras` for the intent. You can get it like so:

```
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    String uri = bundle.getString("uri");
                }
                    break;

                default: {
                }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }, new IntentFilter(id));
```

The `uri` in this case will be like `content://sms/7384`. In this case the `7834` is the `_id` field. Using a content resolver we can get the details of that SMS or MMS.

This is a part of my sending pending intent.

Keep in mind that if you send a multipart SMS that only **one** call back will have the `uri`. The rest will have null for that field.

Comment: "This is a part of my sending pending intent." - This sentence isn't clear to me. Are you saying that you're attaching the URI to the `Intent` used for the `PendingIntent`?

Comment: Nope. this is the broadcast receiver for the sent pending intents when you call the `sendTextMessage` function.

Comment: OK, then this isn't going to work everywhere. Which Android version are you testing under?

Comment: 5.1.1. Are you sure it won't work everywhere? I can show more code if required for clarification.

Comment: That might not be necessary yet. If you're not calling `sentIntent.putExtra("uri", ...)` anywhere in the code you've posted in your question, then, yeah, this won't work everywhere. There is no URI extra on that `Intent` in stock KitKat (4.4), for example. I'm just trying to determine if it's a newer function of Android.

Comment: Then how can I get the URI? Basically I want to get the URI for messages that are __sent__. Obviously I won't know the URI before they are sent.

Comment: I'm using a Galaxy S6 for testing if that makes a difference.

Comment: "Then how can I get the URI?" - Well, that's what you asked in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204990/android-send-sms-pending-intent). I wasn't aware of any recent changes to the `PendingIntent` handling - i.e., the addition of a `"uri"`-keyed extra - but I'm gonna do a little testing, and dig through the source code, when I get a chance.

Comment: Yeah, I remember that. I was trying to moving away from that. Instead of having an observer on the whole SMS table rather just receive a callback.

Comment: Ok, apparently this was added in Lollipop sometime, so if you're only supporting back to that version, you can stick with this. However, if you're supporting previous versions, you'll have to use the alternate method.

Comment: Interesting. So in previous versions we have SentIntent but __not__ with a `uri` call back?

Comment: The sent and delivered `PendingIntent`s have always been available in the `SmsManager#send*` methods. The addition of the URI on the broadcasted sent `Intent` was apparently new with Lollipop. My KitKat device, for example, only has two extras on that `Intent`, keyed with `"LastSentMsg"` and `"simSlot"`. My Lollipop device has also the `"uri"`-keyed extra. I will update my relevant answers accordingly, when I get a minute.

Comment: One thing I'll add is that when you send multi part messages, only __one__ has the `uri` callback. rest has null. That's per my testing.