Android: my onReceive function only getting incoming and not outgoing text messages
I'm working on an Android app that's supposed to listen for both incoming and outgoing SMS messages, format them into JSON, and send them to my local Flask server. I've followed various guides and tutorials, and I believe my code is correct, but I'm encountering a frustrating issue: I'm only receiving incoming SMS messages, not the outgoing ones.
Here's a summary of what I've done:
Permissions: I have the RECEIVE_SMS, READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, INTERNET, and FOREGROUND_SERVICE permissions declared in my AndroidManifest.xml.
Foreground Service: My SmsListenerService is running as a foreground service with a persistent notification.
BroadcastReceiver: I have a BroadcastReceiver inside my service that's listening for both Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION and "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" actions.
JSON Creation and Sending: The code to create the JSON object and send it to the server seems to be working fine for incoming SMS, but it's not triggered for outgoing ones.
Testing: I'm testing on a physical device and have tried sending SMS to multiple numbers.
Code Snippet (SmsListenerService):
package de.dlyt.yanndroid.notifer.service;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import de.dlyt.yanndroid.notifer.MainActivity;
import de.dlyt.yanndroid.notifer.R;

public class SmsListenerService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "SmsListenerService";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "sms_listener_channel";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("SMS Listener")
                .setContentText("Listening for SMS...")
//                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "SMS Listener Channel";
            String description = "Channel for SMS Listener notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "SMS Service created");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT");
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    }


    public static class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

            String messageBody = smsMessages[0].getMessageBody();
                Log.d("Andrew","Hello");
              Log.d("Andrew",messageBody);
//            if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(action) ||
//                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT".equals(action)) {
            if (true){
                for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                    String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String body = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                    long timestamp = smsMessage.getTimestampMillis();

                    JSONObject jsonSms = new JSONObject();
                    String deviceName = Build.MODEL;
                    try {
                        jsonSms.put("deviceName", deviceName != null ? deviceName : "Unknown Device");
                        jsonSms.put("appName", Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(action) ? "incoming" : "outgoing");
                        jsonSms.put("packageName", Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(action) ? "incoming" : "outgoing");
                        jsonSms.put("id",0);
                        jsonSms.put("time", timestamp);
                        jsonSms.put("isOngoing",false);
                        jsonSms.put("Notification Extra","");
                        jsonSms.put("title", address);
                        jsonSms.put("text", body); // Added "body" as the key
                        jsonSms.put("subText", "");
                        jsonSms.put("titleBig", "");
                        jsonSms.put("bigText", "");
                        jsonSms.put("progressIndeterminate", 0);
                        jsonSms.put("progressMax",0);
                        jsonSms.put("progress",0);
                        jsonSms.put("interruptionFilter",0);

                        // Send the JSON object to your server
                        sendToServer(jsonSms.toString(), context);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating JSON object", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private static void sendToServer(String jsonData, Context context) {
            String serverUrl = "http://**.***.**.***:8000"; // Your server URL

            new Thread(() -> {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                        byte[] input = jsonData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
                    }

                    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SMS data sent successfully.");

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                        String responseLine = null;
                        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(responseLine.trim());
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "Server response: " + response.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error sending SMS data. Response Code: " + responseCode);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException while sending SMS data:", e);
                } finally {
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    }


}



You can't observe outgoing SMS like that. The "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" action does not exist in the SDK, and there is no general system broadcast when an SMS is sent. The only way to "intercept" messages is to be the default SMS app and have users send them through your app somehow, but even then, any app using SmsManager directly would essentially bypass yours. If timeliness isn't a concern, you could schedule some sort of task to read the sent messages from the Provider and process them in batches occasionally.

Btw, you generally don't need a constantly-running Service to catch incoming SMS. You can register the Receiver class directly in the manifest for the SMS_RECEIVED action.

so assuming i'm ignoring the way to receive the sms because it would take quite a bit of studying. (though im interested) so you say i need to be the default sms app? is there no other way? i;ve seen someone use the content://sms and use a secondary approach to it to receive this information using the not time sensitive content.. how do i do this

Yeah, I was just writing a comment about the ContentObserver option that I'd neglected to mention above, but that would require you to keep the foreground Service, which I usually try to avoid, since users generally don't appreciate things running all the time.

Here's an example of one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694953, though it might be a little outdated. The example at the start of this one has better details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098069.

Another thing I forgot: WorkManager can be configured to observe the SMS Provider for changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78118503. It will take care of setting up the ContentObserver internally; you wouldn't need to mess with it. You could then do everything in a Worker, if you don't necessarily need instantaneous access to the incoming messages. No foreground Service or separate Receiver class would be needed. Just FYI.
